# Unable to boot and access/mount the root partition

Tags: boot, mount, read-only

I am unable to boot into system.

I was working normally and then as I decided to log out, and pressed Log out option, a long stream of code started to roll down the screen, and nothing else happened. It was I think the filesystem journaling, had the text "ignoring read-only filesystem."

Then I had to force shut down my laptop.
After that, my system loaded up, after a session of FSCK, but root FS would automatically turn to read-only. I multiple times shut down the computer properly and restarted again but it'd be still read-only.

Finally it went down completely and now shows the Grub console.

Interesting part is I have 5 partitions. 1 ext4 and 4 NTFS, out of which I'm able to access 3 of the NTFS ones, but not able to access sda1 (root ext4) and sda2 (NTFS). Please help.

I booted from a live USB and tried to fix but nothing is working.

fdisk

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048  205150207  205148160  97.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        205150208  237819903   32669696  15.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        237819904  649627647  411807744 196.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        649627648 1953523711 1303896064 621.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        649637888 1310240767  660602880   315G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       1310248960 1953521663  643272704 306.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -p /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda1
Could this be a zero-length partition?

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 3465.037168] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 3465.037175] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 3465.040107] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 3465.040161] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3465.040188] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 3465.040201] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[ 3465.040217] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 08 20 00 00 08 00
[ 3465.040229] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 2080 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3465.040250] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 4, async page read
[ 3465.040336] ata1: EH complete

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
mount: /mnt/sda1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Check Image:

[image: 3 of 5 partitions mounted]

UPDATE: For the NTFS partition, should I try installing Windows then running Chkdsk?
Is it a hardware issue and is there a hope of data recovery?

Comment: First to mount a partition that is not setup in your /etc/fstab, you can't just type `mount /dev/sda1` you have to provide a target directory so `mkdir /mnt/some_directory_name` then `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/some_directory_name`. As you have guessed this is a helpfull start to check that your drive and your data are still there.

Comment: You need to **enable networking** when you boot into recovery, otherwise the system will be mounted read-only and you won't be able to fix anything.  In other situations, if Ubuntu keeps switching the drive to read-only, that's an indication of a dying HDD.  If you don't have good backups, make them now.

Comment: @Kasonnara Right I have updated the output in my question. Please check.

Comment: @Nmath Oh is that the case, I'm backuping now